# find batch-job by label client-go

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, client-go

How to list Batch-Job by label-selector. I want to list out the job with a certain label like:
`type: upgrade` or something else.
Looking out for label selector fields while querying job from client-go.

Answer (score 1):

I was making mistake worrying about the `.Get()` method to find job by labelSelector, and thus working hard in the wrong direction.

Here is how you can list out all job with the label-selector
To get job by label-selector, We have to use `.List()` method.

```golang
label := "type=upgrade,name=jiva-upgrade"; 
jobs, err := k.K8sCS.BatchV1().Jobs(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: label})
```